# Sort through master directory to randomly select jpg,pngs from 300 different subdirectories

Tags: python, directory, png, jpeg

I have a master directory that contains 300 sub directories. Each of these 300 subdirectories contains even more subdirectories, which contain jpegs, pngs.

I would like a script that will crawl through main directory, and in to each of the 300 sub main directories. From there, I would like to select one image randomly and have these images put in jpg/png format into a new folder.

I know I can randomly select images from one folder...but I'm asking how to best to navigate through all preceding subdirectories?

Thanks to a post already on this forum I am able to select and printout 20 random images:

```
import os

import random

files_list = []
for root, dirs, files in os.walk("/path/to/master/directory"):
    for file in files:
        if file.endswith(".jpeg") or file.endswith(".png"):
            files_list.append(os.path.join(root, file))

# choose randomally 20 files
print(random.sample(files_list, 20))
```

But I need to figure out how to make sure each of the 300 subdirectories are crawled individually, returning one jpg or png which are then all placed in a new folder...so a new folder with 300 randomly selected images.

Comment: fair comment @ranifisch ...will update OP when I get a chance, for now just wondering if it's actually possible.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [`os.walk`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.walk)(there are more ways, but this is my favorite, you can find more [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3964681/find-all-files-in-a-directory-with-extension-txt-in-python)) function to iterate over all files in a given directory.

Read more about `random.sample` [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html)

```
import os
import random

files_list = []
for root, dirs, files in os.walk("your/path/to/master/dir"):
    for file in files:
        if file.endswith(".jpeg") or file.endswith(".png"):
            files_list.append(os.path.join(root, file))
    
# print 20 random images
print(random.sample(files_list, 20))
```

Comment: I'll give it a try now...as a relative newbie, I wasn't familiar with os.walk

Comment: Thanks @ranifisch...that works, I have updated OP with a change to question.